# Is there any way to make a soft reference or Pointer-like objects using Numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, pointers, soft-references

I was wondering whether there is a way to refer data from many different arrays to one array, but without copying it.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([2,3,4,5,6])
b = np.array([5,6,7,8])

c = np.ndarray([len(a)+len(b)])

offset = 0
c[offset:offset+len(a)] = a
offset += len(a)
c[offset:offset+len(b)] = b
```

However, in the example above, `c` is a new array, so that if you modify some element of `a` or `b`, it is not modified in `c` at all.

I would like that each index of `c` (i.e. `c[0]`, `c[1]`, etc.) refer to each element of both `a` and `b`, but like a pointer, without making a `deepcopy` of the data.

Comment: No can do... You can do it the other way around, i.e. generate slices `a` and `b` from a previously defined `c`, so with some previous planning you may get what you want. But not after the fact.

Comment: This is interested indeed, but I have `a` and `b` "by the self definition of my problem". Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Jaime says, you can't generate a new array whose contents point to elements in multiple existing arrays, but you can do the opposite:

```
import numpy as np

c = np.arange(2, 9)
a = c[:5]
b = c[3:]
print(a, b, c)
# (array([2, 3, 4, 5, 6]), array([5, 6, 7, 8]), array([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]))

b[0] = -1

print(c,)
# (array([ 2,  3,  4, -1,  6,  7,  8]),)
```

---

I think the fundamental problem with what you're asking for is that numpy arrays must be backed by a continuous block of memory that can be [regularly strided](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#internal-memory-layout-of-an-ndarray) in order to map memory addresses to the individual array elements.

In your example, `a` and `b` will be allocated within non-adjacent blocks of memory, so there will be no way to address their elements using a single set of strides.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it seems to me that there must be a way of defining an array of pointers. It should be very useful to know how to define pointers in Python. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: That depends on what exactly you mean by *"an array of pointers"*. As I already explained, the internal memory layout of numpy arrays means that you definitely can't create a new numpy array that references values in two existing arrays that were allocated separately. I think this might be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/247805) - what exactly do you want an *"array of pointers"* for?

Comment: With an array of pointers I mean an array such that each element points to another memory address. But I think you are right, it is not possible. Anyways, you example was very intereseting indeed. Thanks!

Comment: My question was really about *why* you wanted such an array. I see you accepted my answer anyway, but if you wanted to ask a separate follow-up question then I'd strongly suggest you explain the background of your problem more fully - there's probably a good way to solve it with numpy, but we need to know what your actual problem is, rather than just the particular solution you had in mind.