# Faster way to convert list of objects to numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to optimize my code by removing for loops and list comprehension by using numpy arrays.
In general the execution of the code is now faster, BUT there is a thing that bothers me a lot: converting my list with about 110000 elements to a numpy array takes most of the time of the program runtime (5 to 7 seconds, just to initialize an array!)

I have this

```
rec = np.array(records)
```

where `records`is a list of objects.

Is it possible to speed up the creation of this numpy array?

Comment: Why are you first creating a list and then converting it to a numpy array, Create a numpy array instead, if that is possible ?

Comment: where does records come from?

Comment: It is not possible to create directly a numpy array, since the datas come from a sqlite database in django, so the records I get are in a QuerySet...

Comment: Possibly similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/30005735/901925

Comment: What are these records like?

Answer (score 10):

If your list is one dimensional, using `np.fromiter()` is faster than the typical `np.array()`.
Benchmark for an integer list of size 10000 :

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]*1000

%timeit np.array(a,dtype=np.int32)
456 µs ± 7.16 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit np.fromiter(a,dtype=np.int32,count=10000)
242 µs ± 6.65 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: With such a big speed difference I’m surprised that np doesn’t check if the arg is a list/tuple and call fromiter(count=len(a)) internally. The typecheck plus len can’t be more than a microsecond. But maybe it’s not worth it for typical small lists

Answer (score 3):

The way the python stores objects (such as the items in records) is not the same as for numpy. Therefore in order to create the numpy array, each element needs to be accessed and then converted.

As @anmol_uppoal's comment suggests, you should be looking to create a numpy array from the outset. For example

```
rec = np.zeros((SIZE_OF_ARRAY,))
# Set values of rec in the same way you created records, for instance
for i in range(100):
    rec[i] = i+1
```

Getting further optimisations would be linked to where the data is coming from -- if from a file, try storing in a numpy-format, rather than text format. If a database, consider saving the binary values (but this depends heavily on the rest of your application)

Answer (score 0):

when reading data, it generally does not come as numpy arrays. netcdf library that has bindings java or python, to handle multivariable, multifile datasets in  HDF5 or variants. It use an internal optimized array type, but not the numpy type, so conversion is unavoidable.

As example, it takes several minutes for conversion from a netcdf dataset.
step by step timing shows this is only the conversion that takes the time

```py
with CodeTimer("convert np.array"): tcc_obs = np.asarray(tcc_obs)
```

for one array of shape : (725, 759, 96)  ~53 M elements
Code block 'convert np.array' took: 161 s

If anybody has a way to get it better. Logically, it should be better to subset with boolean arrays the netcdf variable, then convert a smaller array, but the code use some numpy function as isin to find common indexes in two tables, which has no equivalent known to me for python arrays.