# how to get the output of input list, as a list using a formula

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary, formula

i need to print a solution list for the input list using the below formula,
this is the code:

```
sub=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
a=[]



for i in sub:
     def res(i):(sub/12)*100 #this is the formula
     a.append(res(i))
print(a)
```

formula:

```
(sub/12)*100
```

i am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\suh\Desktop\se proj 2\backend.py", line 62, in <module>
    a.append(res(i))
  File "c:\Users\suh\Desktop\se proj 2\backend.py", line 61, in res
    def res(i):(sub/12)*100
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things going on here:

First of all, don't define a function inside of a loop. You want to define the function that implements the logic of the formula separately and call it from within the loop.
You also need to use `return` in the function in order to send the calculated value back to whoever called the `formula` function.

Secondly, you want to go over each element in the `sub` list, apply the formula on it and then append the result to a list.

In addition, it is a good idea to provide meaningful variable names (`a` and `res` are not meaningful).

Applying the above, you get this:

```
def formula(num):
    return (num / 12) * 100  # this is the formula


sub = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
sub_after_formula = []
for num in sub:
     sub_after_formula.append(formula(num))
print(sub_after_formula)
```

Output:

```
[8.333333333333332, 16.666666666666664, 25.0, 33.33333333333333, 41.66666666666667, 50.0, 58.333333333333336]
```

As @JonSG mentioned, it is recommended to use the list comprehension instead of the `for` loop in cases like this:

```
sub_after_formula = [formula(x) for x in sub]
```

Comment: For good measure you might add in a note about using `map()` or a comprehension. `sub_after_formula = list(map(formula, sub))` or `sub_after_formula = [formula(x) for x in sub]` as alternate strategies.

Comment: @JonSG You're right - list comprehension is the way to go here, I'll update my answer accordingly. I believe using `map` here is not a good idea as it is recommended to use list comprehension in cases like this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/list-comprehension-vs-map). Thanks

Comment: @SuhasS Happy to help

Answer (score 1):

```
sub=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]    
a=[]    

for i in sub:    
     res = (i/12)*100 #this is the formula    
     a.append(res)    
print(a)
```

You shouldn't make a function in a for loop. In this example as per me no function is needed.
You are getting the error actually because your formula is (sub/12)*100 while sub is a list. i is the item there not sub your formula should be (i/12)*100
You can't divide a list with 12., but an integer which is i here

Comment: Sorry, I was on the phone so couldn't arrange the code

Comment: Well, upvote me please

Comment: @ROOPAMBER No worries, happy to help

Answer (score 1):

For this small list, the list comprehension / map approach is great.

For a larger list, or if you plan to do more mathematical operations on the list, it might be worth looking into the `numpy` library. This often results in a significant speed increase, and can simplify the code.

Once you convert the list to a numpy array, you can perform vectorised operations:

```
sub = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
sub_array = np.array(sub)
result = (sub_array/12) * 100
print(result)
```

Or we can use a function and pass the array directly:

```
def formula(num):
    return (num / 12) * 100

sub_array = np.array(sub)
result = formula(sub_array)
print(result)
```

For a slight speed increase, you can use `formula(np.fromiter(sub,dtype=np.int32))` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/59509701/9555388

Comment: thank you this one works as well